# Make an OpenCV Mat buffer unique

Tags: c++, opencv, shared-ptr

In OpenCV, `cv::Mat` is implicitely shared in memory.

I need to implement a `make_unique` function that ensures a `cv::Mat` doesn't share memory with any other class instance.

Doing mat = `mat.clone();` does the job, but I think it will copy the data even if it wasn't shared.

Is there a more efficient way which avoids copying when not necessary?